# Best way to download data from Sharepoint (I'm in need for some automation)

Tags: json, excel, api, sharepoint, onedrive

Basically there are some shared Excel files on my corporation's Sharepoint and I need local copies of It for data analysis. I am able to manually download all I need, but I need to automate this work somehow.

I'm writing this post because of issues regarding two aspects of this problem:

**Microsoft Licenses**: as I'm using a personal account on a corporation domain (for my work), so Microsoft won't let me setup gateways on Power Automate. I was able to create a Power Automate Flow that does exactly what I need, but my end point is messed up (can't connect to my local machine so I can create the file I need with the data from Sharepoint). I cannot acess these files with other account.

**Two-factor authentication**: I'm unable to use APIs with Sharepoint apparently because of this, and the authentication is something that I cannot disable due to my corporation's policies.

Any workaround is viable? I need some new ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PnP.PowerShell to automate this task.
For authentication issue just register an app on the target site collection and grant is access. Then use this app credentials to connect to the SharePoint site and download the files.

Reference -
To create a new app - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/register-sharepoint-add-ins#to-register-by-using-appregnewaspx

Grant access to this app - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs#setting-up-an-app-only-principal-with-tenant-permissions

Use this app to authenticate - https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Connect-PnPOnline.html#example-3